# How can I perform efficient Deletions in Accumulo across multiple ranges?

Tags: accumulo

I have an index table with the following schema:

```
Row   CF    CQ
Name  POB   DOB
```

How could I efficiently delete multiple rows (i.e. John Doe:New York:01/01/75 , Jane Doe:Miami:06/21/80)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BatchDeleter` and `setRanges` of all the `Range` (rows) that you want to delete

https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/BatchDeleter.html

Comment: Given my schema would I use Range.exact() to create multiple Ranges, one for each record I want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

```
BatchDeleter deleter= conn.createBatchDeleter("Table Name", new Authorizations(), 1, config);
Collection<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<Range>();
Scanner tableScannerRange= conn.createScanner("TableName", new Authorizations());
tableScannerRange.setRange(new Range("XXXX"));
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : tableScannerRange) {
                            ranges.add(new Range(entry.getKey().getRow()));
}
deleter.setRanges(ranges);
deleter.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Use Put Delete

```
Mutation mutation_data = new Mutation("  ");

                        mutation_data.putDelete(CF,CQ);
```